# md5 multithreaded bruteforce

Tags: python, multithreading, md5, brute-force

I use python 2.7, and I have a simple multitheaded md5 dict brute:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import md5
import Queue
import threading
import traceback

md5_queue = Queue.Queue()


def Worker(queue):
    while True:
        try:
            item = md5_queue.get_nowait()
        except Queue.Empty:
            break
        try:
            work(item)
        except Exception:
            traceback.print_exc()

        queue.task_done()


def work(param):
    with open('pwds', 'r') as f:
        pwds = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

    for pwd in pwds:
        if md5.new(pwd).hexdigest() == param:
            print '%s:%s' % (pwd, md5.new(pwd).hexdigest())


def main():
    global md5_queue
    md5_lst = []
    threads = 5

    with open('md5', "r") as f:
        md5_lst = [x.strip() for x in f.readlines()]

    for m in md5_lst:
        md5_queue.put(m)    # add md5 hash to queue

    for i in xrange(threads):
        t = threading.Thread(target=Worker, args=(md5_queue,))
        t.start()

    md5_queue.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Work in 5 threads. Each thread reads one hash from queue and checks it with list of passwords. Pretty simple: 1 thread 1 check in 'for' loop.

I want to have a little bit more: 1 thread and few threads to check passwords. So work() should read hash from queue and start a new number of threads to check passwords (1 thread hash, 10 thread there check for passwords). For example: 20 threads with hash and 20 threads to brute the hash in each thread. Something like that.

How can I do this?

P.S. Sorry for my explanation, ask if you did not understood what I want.

P.P.S. It's not about bruting md5, it's about multi-threading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default implementation of Python (called CPython) uses a [Global Interpreter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) (GIL) that effectively only allows one thread to be running at once.  For I/O bound multithreaded applications, this is not usually a problem, but for CPU-bound applications like yours, it means you're not going to see much of a multicore speedup.

I'd suggest using a different Python implementation that doesn't have a GIL such as Jython, or rewriting your code to use a different language that doesn't have a GIL.  Writing it in natively compiled code is a good idea, but most scripting languages that have an MD5 function usually implement that in native code anyways, so I honestly wouldn't expect much of a speedup between a natively compiled language and a scripting language.

Comment: Well, there's another solution to use all cores - multiprocessing. This module from standard library has similar API to threading and allows to get rid of GIL limitations. Though you receive no threads, but processes doing the job.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the following code would be a considerably more efficient program than your example code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

try:
    import md5
    digest = lambda text: md5.new(text).hexdigest()
except ImportError:
    import hashlib
    digest = lambda text: hashlib.md5(text.encode()).hexdigest()

def main():
    passwords = load_passwords('pwds')
    check_hashes('md5', passwords)

def load_passwords(filename):
    passwords = {}
    with open(filename) as file:
        for word in (line.strip() for line in file):
            passwords.setdefault(digest(word), []).append(word)
    return passwords

def check_hashes(filename, passwords):
    with open(filename) as file:
        for code in (line.strip() for line in file):
            for word in passwords.get(code, ()):
                print (word + ':' + code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It has been written with both Python 2.x and 3.x and should be able to run on either of those languages.